# NativeScript RadDataForm validateAndCommitAll doesn't work on iOS

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to validate the form in a Nativescript Vue project, by accessing the form via refs and use `validateAndCommitAll` method of `RadDataForm` class.

On Android it just works and shows the alert, but on iOS it does nothing.

What would be a solution?

Playground link with sample code: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=E7pBtn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to set the `commitMode` to `Manual`.

```
 <RadDataForm :source="eventInfo" ref="eventForm" row="0"
         commitMode="Manual">
```